# Sorting out a list of items in ascending date

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, razor

My page has a list of events I'm sorting into order by the following line of code:

```
 results = CurrentPage.Children
   .Where("eventDate >= minDate AND eventDate < maxDate", month)
   .OrderBy("eventDate desc")
   .Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage)
   .Take(itemsPerPage);
```

This returns all my items in descending order by date. So right now it goes from `August 2015`, `July 2015` and so on. What I need is for it show the reverse.

I've tried looking to see if there is an ascending call in the `OrderBy()` method but I can't find anything. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using desc means to descend. You should use ASC like below and it should work.

```
results = CurrentPage.Children.Where("eventDate >= minDate AND eventDate < maxDate", month)
                           .OrderBy("eventDate asc")
                           .Skip(currentPage * itemsPerPage)
                           .Take(itemsPerPage);
```